# How to understand notation in the Java docs?

Tags: javadoc

Given, I know that `<T>` or `<T, V extends Number>` is the formal type parameter section. This is a declaration of the formal type parameter T ( type variables ). A type variable is an unqualified identifier used as a type in class, interface, static and non-static methods, and constructor bodies.

But I don't understand what means `TypeParameter: {TypeParameterModifier} Identifier [TypeBound]` in the documentation.

What does mean `{}`? Optional arguments?

What does mean `[]`?

Where `{}` and `[]` in `<T, V extends Number>`  ?

https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-4.html#jls-4.4

```
TypeParameter:
  {TypeParameterModifier} Identifier [TypeBound]
TypeParameterModifier:
  Annotation
TypeBound:
  extends TypeVariable
  extends ClassOrInterfaceType {AdditionalBound}
AdditionalBound:
  & InterfaceType
```

Comment: The notation of the language grammar is defined in [#2.4](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-2.html#jls-2.4): {x} means zero or more and [x] means zero or one. Note 'T extends Number' is part of a single TypeParameter in 4.4, but the `< >` around the list and any commas in it are defined in 8.1.2.

Comment: PS: 'java docs' in general mean any docs (documentation) about Java, but the term (and tag) 'javadoc' means specifically documentation of classes, methods, etc in a library, often but not only the standard library, extracted from special comments in the library source; this does not include the language definition, because the language definition is not extracted from comments in the source code of a library.

Comment: @dave_thompson_085, thank you! If you add answer - I'll take it like answer.